# s3 bucket policy for presigned urls

Tags: python, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tastypie

I am new to amazon s3 and I am trying to upload image to my s3 bucket by using presigned url.somehow it is showing me **access denied**.My url format is

```
https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/imagename.jpeg&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Expires=XXXX&Signature=XXXX
```

I search on the internet and came to know that signature url do not need bucket policy to upload so I have not created any bucket policy.

**I have written a code in python:**

```
   class PreSignImage(Resource):

    results = fields.DictField(attribute='aws_string')
    class Meta:
        object_class=FeedObject
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = Authentication()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        authorization = Authorization()
        include_resource_uri=False
        resource_name = 'upload_image'
        always_return_data = True
    def get_object_list(self, bundle):
        results = list()
        file_name=bundle.request.GET['file_name']
        file_type=bundle.request.GET['file_type']

        s3=boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_KEY)
        presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(Bucket = settings.S3_BUCKET,
                                                    Key = file_name,
                                                    Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
                                                    Conditions = [
                                                                    {"acl": "public-read"},
                                                                    {"Content-Type": file_type}
                                                                ],
                                                    ExpiresIn = 36000
                                                    )
        screenobj = FeedObject()
        screenobj.aws_string=presigned_post
        results.append(screenobj)
        #data=json.dumps({'data': presigned_post,'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (settings.S3_BUCKET, file_name)})
        #response=HttpResponse(content=data,status=200,content_type="application/json;")
        #response['Content-Length']=len(data)
        return results
```

**trying to upload image from ios app:**

```
-(void) uploadImage:(UIImage *)image atUrl:(NSString *)url withMimeType:(NSString *)mimeType {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);
    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *client = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:requestURL];
    client.requestSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setValue:mimeType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:imageData];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[imageData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"public-read" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-amz-acl"];
    [request setURL:requestURL];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [client dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
        }
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

stuck from last 2 days still I am unable to upload an image to my bucket.Please help

Comment: Can you check if creator of signed url has the permission for that request+ your signed url will work upto specific time period only. refer:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: @HarshalBulsara  i have checked and passing expires value as 36000 which is acceptable..still it doesnt work

Comment: The user who has created signurl has the permission to add the object in bucket, cos by default it will be private?

Comment: Here's a Gist I wrote that shows a generic upload resource: https://gist.github.com/SeanHayes/6e7c6094f6a8265e8b56

It has example GET signed URL, example PUT signed URL, and example S3 form policy. Maybe something in there will point you in the right direction.

Comment: The user referenced by the AccessKey must have permissions for the operation you are trying to perform. What policies are associated with that User?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using python code to generate signature.how can I specify username while generating presigned url?

Comment: @HarshalBulsara I have not created any policy for any user.I am just send signature and image with awsaccessid and expire values

Comment: The user who created signurl should have permission to add the data, so that policy must be there in S3 for that user

Comment: @HarshalBulsara How can I specify user while generating signed url.what parameter should I pass to my python code?I seached But did not  find anything about this.

Comment: The account you use to generate signurl that account should have permission to add/update object to that bucket, if it is there than only signurl will be able to upload the object make sense?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using AWS SDK for iOS? The iOS SDK will make your existing code very easy. Have a look at AWSS3TransferUtility in the iOS SDK.

Also, have you set correct policy for the role you are using to upload the file?

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: @RohanDubal I dont want to put aws access key and secret key inside ios app.

Comment: You could use Cognito Identity service for this. Its a free service and gets over this issue.

Comment: Cognito also gives anyone with access to the iOS device to sniff your tokens to get permission to your bucket , allso for free and included in the package.